# Tweet from AS3 and execute a callback

Tags: actionscript-3

There is some way to make a tweet from an  AS3 app, passing a message 
and a url to tweet, and **executing a callback** 
if the tweet was succesfully posted?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [tweetr](http://wiki.swfjunkie.com/tweetr) library to post a status update, and then listen for the [COMPLETE](http://tweetr.swfjunkie.com/docs/com/swfjunkie/tweetr/events/TweetEvent.html) event which will indicate that the update was successful.

There is even an example: http://svn.swfjunkie.com/websvn/filedetails.php?repname=Tweetr&path=%2Ftrunk%2Fexamples%2Ftweetr%2Fflex%2Fexample_2.mxml.

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks to reply. I'm trying to access the link you recommend me but user/pass are required. Can you paste the code here? Thanks!